# [Crash][ExoPlayer] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getDummyDrmSessionManager() when running app with library-dash module

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I am having crash when trying to play DASH stream using customized ExoPlayer library-dash module version 2.11.3, imported as an .aar archive. Here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getDummyDrmSessionManager()Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/drm/DrmSessionManager; in class Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/drm/DrmSessionManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DrmSessionManager' appears in base.apk)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.DashMediaSource$Factory.<init>(DashMediaSource.java:118)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.DashMediaSource$Factory.<init>(DashMediaSource.java:101)
```

Interesting thing is that crash occurs with **signed app only**. When I simply run it from studio, it works fine.

Here is the source code in ExoPlayer library-core module that I am having issue with

```
public interface DrmSessionManager<T extends ExoMediaCrypto> {

  /** Returns {@link #DUMMY}. */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  static <T extends ExoMediaCrypto> DrmSessionManager<T> getDummyDrmSessionManager() {
    return (DrmSessionManager<T>) DUMMY;
  }
```

I do realize there is a Java 8 compatibility issue between my app and dash library being imported, and it probably needs some gradle fine tunning, but I cannot find what needs to be changed in my project to support this.

For project purposes, however, I had to modify the library-dash module, and to use it in my project as .aar. The **build.gradle** file inside Exo library-dash module from which I am building the .aar library, is unchanged and I made sure it contains these lines (these lines are also placed in **library-core** module of ExoPlayer project)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion project.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

In my project, **app** module using this library contains these lines, and additionally this line

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

The rest of the ExoPlayer library is used from remote repository:

```
api 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.11.4'
api 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.11.4'
api 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.11.4'
api project(':lib-dash')
```

Root build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

What more needs to be added to support locally built .aar library-dash module and to avoid this kind of Java 8 incompatibilities?